# How do I restore Inee to sanity?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind

I'm just blundering around the Gateway Inn looking for <strike>loot</strike> a [ghost](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Gateway_Ghost). After having a chat with [Inee](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Inee) I open a door and whaddya know, a ghost starts wailing on me. After dispatching it I notice something is still attacking me, and it looks like Inee has gone crazy, punching my glass armor with bare hands. I've tried a few different spells to calm him down, but no luck. I could just leave, but is it possible to bring Inee back to sanity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems something hit Inee during the fight and caused him to attack.

- You can simply leave and wait for his aggression to go away.
- You can use the calm humanoid spell to try to pacify him.
- You can use the charm spell on him to stop him from attacking.
- After you pacified him, you can try to use speechcraft to improve his disposition to make future attacks less likely.
- You can use demoralize humanoid to send him fleeing.
- You can use paralyze to stop him from attacking.
- It's possible he is just under the effect of a frenzy humanoid spell and will stop attacking on his own in a few minutes.
- You can try using fisticuffs against him and hope he surrenders after a while.

If all of this doesn't stop him permanently from attacking you, you have no option but to pacify or ignore him whenever you enter the inn or to kill him.

Comment: Ah right, the area of effect of my weapon! I think it was just a soul trap though, but I guess an NPC would be justified to take offense :)